# java syntax question

Tags: java, generics

What do these lines of code do?

```
private interface ComparisonCallback<ComparisonT>
{
    public ComparisonT getComparisonValue(CVRDataElement e);
}
```

followed by this method declaration:

```
public <ComparisonType> List<MyDataTable> getGenericSubTable(ComparisonCallback<ComparisonType> cc)
```

Specifically, I don't understand the ComparisonType tag - does this have to do with generics?

Comment: That syntax doesn't look quite right. Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: @Joe that is the correct syntax for generics in Java (except for the missing space...)

Comment: Shouldn't ComparisonT and ComparisonType be the same word instead of different?

Comment: Not to mention, the method declaration isn't actually IN the interface. This has confusion written all over it.

Comment: no, ComparisonT and ComparisonType are different words.  This is code that someone rewrote for me (I am new to Java and write very basic code) and gave back.  I am trying to understand it now.

Comment: I still don't understand how you can have a method declaration following an interface declaration. A method has to be inside of a class or interface

Comment: oh, sorry - both are defined inside another class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does this have to do with generics

Yes. You can read up about generics [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the link - what I had read previously on generics didn't explain type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The first interface is the definition of a callback function to be used in the getGenericSubTable method.

The getGenericSubTable parameterizes the return value of the callback function, so it's saying that to do what it needs to do it needs the callback function but that it doesn't care what the type of its return type is.

What it probably means is that you use the callback to return the object that you want it to use for comparison from the CRVDataElement object.